# JavaScript localStorage, only retrieving values the second time round

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to retrieve the input from the user on this page and then display it as a title on the next page which load when the user clicks the arrow. When the page loads the first time you can enter a name and click next however No Hello message is displayed, but if you go back with the browser arrows, enter the name and submit the correct message is displayed. Thank you

```
  <body>
    <h1 class="message">Welcome</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="field-name">
        <img src="/img/User.svg" alt="" class="userIcon" />

        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="text_box" required />

        <a href="/home/home.html" class="arrow inactive"
          ><img src="/img/arrow.svg" alt="" class="arrow_icon"/></a>

      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

The Script for this page:

```
const arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow");
const textBox = document.querySelector(".text_box");
const name = textBox.value;

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  textBox.addEventListener("input", () => {
    arrow.classList.remove("inactive");
  });
  arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem("username", name);
  });
});
```

Script for the page where the name should be displayed:

```
const paragraph = document.querySelector(".text");
const UserName = localStorage.getItem("username");
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  paragraph.textContent = UserName;
});
```

video of what happens if my explanation wasnt great: https://ufile.io/yl37ir60

Comment: @Chev it's that `<a>` in the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are initializing the `name` value before the user updates the value and clicks the link.

Move it within the handler like below so you always get the latest value:

```
  arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem("username", textBox.value);
  });
```